# Eclipse: Android dependencies

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

I have update Google AdMob in my project from 6.2.1 to 6.4.1 but somehow eclipse fails. You can see it here:

[image]

Here is the error messag
*Archive for required library: 'C:/Users/.../libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.2.1.jar' in project '...' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file.*

Can you help with that?

BR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go To

```
Project-->BuildPath-->in library tab-->click Add external jars-->
             Move to YourSdk_directory\extras\google\admob_ads_sdk
```

Comment: Cool this worked :) Didn't know I could take it from there but is't obvious ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.2.1.jar from the library and again add it..
Then **Refresh** the project and **clean** it and then check..

Comment: I did delete it but how do I add it again?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have updated from 6.2.1 to 6.4.1 then why is that 6.2.1 jar file still there in your referenced library. **Remove that jar file from there**.

Also check that 6.4.1.jar in Import and export section

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but not after getting the new Admob jar but after updating to latest Android SDK, I solved it by creating a libs folder manually into the project file and copy pasted the library into it straight away. after that it worked perfectly.