# Cannot reference an android library project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, configuration

I am trying to add a library project as detailed on http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

Last week I could do it but now all of a sudden I cannot reference any library project:

[image: Project Selection window is disabled]

As you can see everything in the "Project Selection" window is disabled. This is the
window I get when I click on Properties -> Android -> Add.. (in the Library widget group).
I tried reinstalling eclipse and creating a new project but no luck.

I am trying to install the "Google Play services" extra (which shows as downloaded
under Android SDK Manager).

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: file-->import-->Existing android code into workspace-->browse and add google-play-services_lib

Comment: Is the Google Play Service project open in Eclipse? If yes, check in the project properties if the checkbox "Is Library" is checked

Comment: check this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438875/eclipse-android-dependencies/16439077#16439077

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add code as a library, you first need to import it into your Eclipse workspace (right-click your Package Explorer, select 'Import...', 'Android', 'Existing Android code into workspace...'.), and then define it as a 'Library', by selecting 'is library' in that project's properties window.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the library project is a library.

go to your library project->properties->Android-> select your checkbox to "is Library"

Answer (score 1):

How stupid, I just needed to first import the project library into eclipse
before being able to reference it. The file was under:

adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services

Sorry for the post.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import library project into your work space
1.Right Click on project go to import
2.Existing android code into work space
3.Browse for directory just go to the sdk and extra and add the project
4.Important thing is that tick the copy project into work space and finish.
5.After that go to project properties and android and add the library project then apply

its works fine for me