# Unknown errors, what are these?

Tags: android

Sometimes I'm not able to run my project because of some errors. The errors are not in my code, but somewhere else. I don't understand what they are or how I fix them. This is what's shown in my Console, in my android project in eclipse:

```
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:71: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:80: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:61: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v23\styles_base_text.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:45: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:49: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:57: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v11\styles_base.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:195: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v11\styles_base.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ProgressBar'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:199: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v11\styles_base.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Spinner'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:110: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-ldltr-v21\styles_base.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v23\styles_base.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:107: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:114: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:104: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:119: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:131: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:136: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:122: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:125: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:139: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:143: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:147: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:151: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:157: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:161: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:165: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:90: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:94: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:98: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:169: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.EditText'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:187: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.CheckBox'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:189: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.RadioButton'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:64: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:173: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.RatingBar'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v23\styles_base.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.RatingBar.Indicator'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v23\styles_base.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.RatingBar.Small'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:175: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.SeekBar'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:177: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:179: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Small'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v23\styles_base.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:181: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:183: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:191: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ImageButton'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:203: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:205: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:185: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ButtonBar'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v12\styles_base.xml:22: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textCursorDrawable'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v12\styles_base.xml:28: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textCursorDrawable'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:38: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:40: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:42: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v14\styles_base_text.xml:22: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAllCaps'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:60: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:62: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v23\styles_base_text.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:46: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:50: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:52: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:54: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:56: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:58: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:20: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:25: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:24: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentEnd'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:33: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:37: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:42: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toEndOf'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:41: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_toStartOf'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:47: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:52: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:51: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:57: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:56: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:61: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:65: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] 
[2016-07-05 09:08:37 - Rodekruis] G:\ICT_alg\01 Applicaties\Android App\Software\appcompat_v7\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:69: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
```

Comment: You need to add following dependencies - 1) compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:*.*.*'  2) compile 'com.android.support:design:*.*.*'

Comment: Eclipse is history now, Use android studio with regular updates to prevent such errors.

Comment: @MohammedAtif It's just one project for school, I already have eclipse and I'm working with this now. I'm close to finished so not gonna change the entire software now. Do you have a solution for these errors?

Comment: @OnkarNene How do I do that? Sorry i'm not too experienced yet.

Comment: try this link,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438875/eclipse-android-dependencies
check update your sdk settings and check whether you have the dependencies as mentioned by @OnkarNene .

Comment: I didn't read, you are using eclipse. Okay then you need to add it as a library, update your SDK and google for how to add appcompat-v7 library in eclipse. But i strongly recommend ANDROID STUDIO for app development

Comment: its noting but simple style problem bcz you are missing dependecy as mention by Onkar Nene. and it will automatically solved if you just import your project to android studio.. you only have to do is download missing sdk attributes.

Comment: eclipse is the worst thing i've seen in my life.. believe me bro you will love it when you start android studio..

Comment: People like I said, I'm close to finishing my school project using eclipse. I've been using it for like 4 months now I'm not gonna change the entire thing to android studio for 1 or 2 weeks. Just asked for help on this one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're facing such errors because appcompat_v7 library is missing or not added accurately in your project.

For solving such issues you can do these things...

1. Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Library using the SDK Manager.

   Go to SDK Manager-->Extras-->android support library(click checkbox and download it)
2. Create a library project and ensure the required JAR files are included in the project's build path:

   1. Select File > Import.
   2. Select Existing Android Code Into Workspace and click Next.
   3. Browse to the SDK installation directory and then to the Support Library folder. For example, if you are adding theappcompat project, browse to /extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/.
   4. Click Finish to import the project. For the v7 appcompat project, you should now see a new project titled android-support-v7-appcompat.
   5. In the new library project, expand the libs/ folder, right-click each .jar file and select Build Path > Add to Build Path. For example, when creating the the v7 appcompat project, add both the android-support-v4.jar andandroid-support-v7-appcompat.jar files to the build path.
   6. Right-click the library project folder and select Build Path > Configure Build Path.
   7. In the Order and Export tab, check the .jar files you just added to the build path, so they are available to projects that depend on this library project. For example, the appcompat project requires you to export both the android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar files.
   8. Uncheck Android Dependencies.
   9. Click OK to complete the changes.

then build and clean your project.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I don't understand step 2. I can't get to the file, there is no extra's or something like that, no support either.

Comment: Browse to your SDK installation directory then.....\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat.....for Ex......my sdk is install in D drive, vishal folder name, Android_SDK is sub folder D:\Vishal\Android_SDK\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat

Comment: Followed every step. Cleaned my project, build atomatically is enabled, the same errors still show up..